# Angularjs: Order and Filter by array intersect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

this is my condition: I retrieve by async call the list of users with their categories.

The client can select the categories.

Now, I have to show only users who have, inside their own categories, those selected from the client, order by how many own categories matches with the selected.

Example. (The number inside the brackets is the ID)

```
User B - Cats: - (no one)
User C - Cats: [7]Cat7, [2]Cat2
User A - Cats: [1] Cat1, [2]Cat2, [5]Cat5
```

Cats selected by client: [2], [1], [8]

So here, user B will not appear and the order of the remaining is A (2 matches), C (1 match).

This is a plunkr, I don't know where to start.

http://plnkr.co/edit/oNlD8T?p=preview

It's better to do in Angular (and how?) or do a new async call (watching the selected cats) and the server process all? (Server side with PHP, I don't know how to do this with nodejs)

Comment: You can define your own filter function. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `filter` filter with custom expression `function(value, index, array)` which will you can compare to the selected array.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

another way is to use lodash, it has `_.some` and `_.intersection` which will make it easier to write the custom expression.

https://lodash.com/docs#some 
https://lodash.com/docs#intersection

you can also make a custom filter of your own `filter(name, filterFactory)`:
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plunker for you [plnkr.co/edit/nHVX5EbWYLarHnHR3LPQ?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/nHVX5EbWYLarHnHR3LPQ?p=preview)
Hope this helps your requirement.

I just modified the existing code. Added a condition to check if the length of the array is greater than zero ng-show="user.cats.length > 0".

```
   <ul>
  <li ng-show="user.cats.length > 0"  ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.name }} - <span ng-repeat="userCat in user.cats" style="margin-right:10px;"><strong>[{{ userCat.id }}]</strong> {{ userCat.label }}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Also note that the greater than symbol( > 0) is not really necessary for ng-show. It just adds clarity to the solution.

Also as Alon Valadji suggested, I updated the plunker with both ng-show and ng-if. Check this article [angular-performance ng-show-vs-ng-if](http://www.codelord.net/2015/07/28/angular-performance-ng-show-vs-ng-if/) and decide based on your requirement.

Comment: it is nice workaround, however, in more complex situation it will not be sufficient. best it to use filters.

Comment: @AlonValadji yes, i agree with you :). But, here the requirement was simple and use of filters would just complicate the code.

Comment: it is better to use `ng-if`. and there will be performance issues with larger data.

Comment: For the  condition >0 it's wrong. The client can choose also to not select the categories, so that result has to be shown.

Comment: @DaniloPolani what exactly is your requirement?

Comment: @SukeshKotian is to show only users who have one (or more) of the categories choosen by the client. A simple matching of tags with filter.

After this, also order those users for the number of matching (ex: A has 2 matches, so it's the first)